# How to write multicolumn under another multicolumn

Tags: multicolumn

Is it possible to make multicolumn under another multicolumn?
Let under A we have B & C.
Now again under B, we have D & E. I try to write this. But how to include D& E?

```
\begin{table*}[htp]
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
\hline
X & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A}\\
\hline
  &  B&C\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! As I understand your requirement, you need one more column.

Comment: You can also nest a tabular inside a tabular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{tabular}{|cccc|}
\hline
X & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{A}    \\
\hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} & C \\
  & D & E                 &  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```